# Macro not able to find another

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run a macro in workbook B using a macro in the current file (i.e. workbook A) - i get the following error:

```
Run-time error '1004':

Cannot run the macro 'Workbookname!Macroname'. The macro may not be available in the workbook or all macros may be disabled
```

Now, I checked all the spellings (i.e. workbookname and macroname) and all of them are fine, but when I go to the workbook B, I am unable to find the macro in the list of macros available in that workbook - please advise!

---

Workbook B is calling Workbook A macro like this:

```
Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Open("Workbookname") 
Application.Run wbTemp.Name & "!" & macroName, folderName 
wbTemp.Close True
```

Comment: **Post the code that attempts to run the external macro.**

Comment: Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Open("Workbookname")
    Application.Run wbTemp.Name & "!" & macroName, folderName
    wbTemp.Close True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wbTemp.Name countains spaces or other characters that the program doesn't like.

My own code :

`StringVar = Application.Run("'" & Wb.Name & "'!Taille_de ", sh.Name)`

where `taille_de` is a function , and `sh.name` is an argument for the function.

and to call a sub with argument :

`Call Application.Run("'" & wb.Name & "'!Module11.son_par-type", Sh.Name)`

or

`Application.Run "'" & wb.Name & "'!Module11.son_par-type " & Sh.Name`

please adapt the code to your needs.

Comment: thanks a lot! so turns out you cant have spaces in the name, so i put in underscores betweens the words in the names

Comment: you can do that, but with my code line it works even with spaces or whatever strange characters

Answer (score 1):

Open the VBE and use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to ensure that the procedure actually exists in the `wbTemp` workbook.

If it does not exist, then that is your problem.

> I am trying to run a macro in workbook B using a macro in the current file (i.e. workbook A)

I suspect that is your problem.  You cannot invoke the macro this way.  If it exists in file A, and you want to run it on file B, then you can just call it normally. This of course assumes that your procedure is written correctly and is capable of executing on *other* workbook files.  If you rely on `ActiveWorkbook`, `ThisWorkbook`, or `Select` methods, it is likely to fail because it is not set up to run on other files.

Comment: I was able to call it before (I AM opening the wbTemp in the code before running the macro in it). But now, I have this macro module in workbook B (I also saved the file) - but when I try to search for it, I cannot see it in the list of macros in that work book (even though I can see it in the project tab of MS VB)

Comment: You're going to need to provide more information. Please edit/update your original question to include more detail about what you are doing.  It is not clear to me, for instance, whether the procedure actually exists in both files (screenshot would be very helpful -- you can upload to imgur.com and include a link to show this), nor which file is attempting to call which macro from which workbook, etc. Also, what do you mean by "the list of macros"?